# Isomorphism with cyclotomic extension

Tags: galois-theory

Let $K$ be a field with $\mbox{char}(K)=0$. I know that if $\xi$ is a primitive $n$-th root of the unity and $K(\xi)\big/K$ is a cyclotomic extension, then $\mbox{Gal}\left(K(\xi)\big/K\right)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_n^*$ (the multiplicative group).

However, I've found in some examples that they use that $\mbox{Gal}\left(K(\xi)\big/K\right)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_n^*$. I wonder when this is possible.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant with "the multiplicative group without the zero", but $\,\left(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z\right)^*\,$ is *not* the original group (ring, in fact) without the zero, but the multiplicative group of all units modulo $\,n\,$. Unless $\,n\,$ is a prime, this is less than the non-zero elements.

Comment: +1 Well, that helped indeed. Could you provide an example, please?

Comment: An example is furnished by any $n$ that’s not a prime. Like $n=4$.

Comment: So, it would be $\mathbb (Z/4\mathbb Z)^* = \left\{1,\xi, \xi^2\right\}$, right?

Comment: No, it is $\,\left(\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\right)^*=\{1,3\}\,$ , multiplicatively. A group of order two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathrm{Gal}(K(\xi)/K)\cong (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$ is true when $K=\mathbb{Q}$. More generally, it is true if the $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial is irreducible over $K$.

Answer (score 0):

For $n$ a prime, and $K = \mathbf{Q}$, you will indeed get $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbf{Q}(\xi)/\mathbf{Q}) \cong \mathbf{Z}_n \setminus \{ 0 \}$.

But then if you understand $\mathbf{Z}_n^{\star}$ to be the *group of invertible elements* of (the multiplicative monoid of) $\mathbf{Z}_n$, then $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbf{Q}(\xi)/\mathbf{Q}) \cong \mathbf{Z}_n^{\star}$ for all $n$.